# What is the meaning of 副助?

Tags: translation, meaning, dictionary, abbreviations

In 大辞泉 (via *goo* [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34861/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B/)) at the first line I found the phrase

> ［副助］種々の語に付く。

What is the meaning of 副助? Can not find it..

Comment: it means 'adverb', more like 'help adverb'. In this context it means you can use か as a help adverb in counting words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries usually list abbreviations. 副助 stands for 副助詞 "adverbial particle", i.e. [副助] = [*adv. part.*].

The suffix 詞 is added to all parts of speech and is omitted in the abbreviations. There are also 副詞 "adverb" and 助詞 "particle" which would be abbreviated [副] and [助].

Comment: Here's the list of abbreviations of 大辞泉: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/help/jn/09_04.html